What is the strange Microsoft Teams Add-on not loaded in Outlook for one user only?
I am using Office 2019 and Teams on Windows 10, the outlook can add new team meeting, I bought a new laptop which is Windows 11 Pro + Office 2021, then I download teams and installed, but found the add new team meeting missing (as pictured).
I tried following so far all failed:

Remove add-in and re-add
Repair and update office
Windows update
Repair Assistant
Online update by Power Shell
ADD add-on registry value %SystemRoot%\System32\regsvr32.exe /n /i:user <path>\x64\Microsoft.Teams.AddinLoader.dll

All failed, but most strange is - when I use another user name login Windows, outlook and teams, the add-on loaded successfully, same machine and all same.
Any ideas?
Cannot Teams icon.



Add-on looks normal.




AS i know, there are several reasons why the add-in may not display. And i notice that " when I use another user name login Windows, outlook and teams, the add-on loaded successfully, same machine and all same", please check if the user must have administrator permissions on the computer. Note:
Install the Teams app as an administrator of the Windows computer.
One requirement for successfully installing the add-in on a Windows computer is that the user must have administrator permissions on the computer.  This is a requirement because COM add-ins to Outlook write to the Windows registry, and only administrators can modify the registry.  If the user who wants to schedule Teams meetings in Outlook is not an administrator, an administrator must install the Teams app first, and then the user can sign in and run Outlook.
More information: Why can't I see the Microsoft Teams Meeting add-in for Outlook?
